# Integration with respect to $B_H(t) B_H(s) - \mathbb{E} \{ B_H ( t ) \, B_H ( s) \}$

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, gaussian, rough-paths

The time-derivative $\frac{dB_H}{dt}$ of the fractional Brownian motion may be interpreted as a random Schwartz distribution acting on a test function by
$$
\left\langle \frac{dB_H}{dt}, f \right\rangle = \int f(t) \, dB_H(t),
$$
where the right-hand side is defined via white noise analysis, rough paths theory or just Young integral if $H>1/2$.

I am interested in the following question: is it possible to make sense of
$$
\frac{d^2}{dt \, ds} \Big[ B_H ( t) \, B_H(s) - \mathbb{E} \left\{ B_H ( t ) \, B_H ( s ) \right\} \Big]
$$
as a random generalized function and develop the corresponding integration theory?

---

In particular, I would like to make sense of
$$
\int f( t, s ) \, d \mu ( t, s )
\quad \text{for} \quad
\mu ( t, s ) = B_H ( t ) \, B_H ( s ) - \mathbb{E} \{ B_H ( t ) \, B_H ( s ) \}
$$
for non-random but not necessarily bounded $f$.

Comment: The problem is that you cannot compute the product of distributions, and so that expression doesn't make sense. Perhaps an alternative for your problem is to consider multiple integrals from rough path theory i.e.

$$\int_{t,s}f(s,t)dB_{t}\otimes dB_{s}$$
but I don't know the context of your problem.

Comment: @ThomasKojar, yes, the product of the distributions is one issue. However, multiple Wiener-Ito integrals with respect to fBm such as $\int f(t, s) \, dB_H(t) \, dB_H(s)$ seem to be well-defined, see Biagini's "Stochastic calculus for fBm", Section 3.9.

Comment: @ThomasKojar, I was more interested in making it zero-mean, which is why this $-\mathbb{E} \{ B_H ( t ) \, B_H ( s ) \}$ is needed.